# app-root not found after update to angular 6

Tags: angular6

I've updated my Angular Project from 5.2.11 to 6.1.0.

I was using the update instructions from Angular and now the compiler is working without any errors.

Now I visit localhost:4200 and `app-root` could not be found.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (VM3279 vendor.js:69776)
```

**app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...,
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
...

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**index.html**

```
<app-root>
  <div class="app-loading">
    <img src="../../assets/images/icon.svg">
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code **router rules** just before `@NgModule({...` in **app.module**

Example:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home-page',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'home-page',
    component: HomePageComponent,
  },
  { 
    path: 'foo-page', 
    component: FooPageComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: NotFoundComponent 
  }
];
```

Add into `imports:[...`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes
)
```

And remember that `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be served only as "routing controller"